# Spring Boot 2.0.3 and Hibernate JPA NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created a new spring boot project with latest stable release but need to include some extra things like envers etc. Without envers the project would not compile. I have tried to test with different versions of Hibernate (4 and 5) and JBoss 'jboss-logmanager (with version 2 and 3) but unfortunately it always gives  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

It seems that Hibernate 4 and 5 both rely on JBoss logging and JBoss logging 2 and 3 both does not have the method with above signatures. My application is deploying on built in Tomcat with Spring Boot.

Here are my execution logs:

```
Executing: gradle :run
Arguments: [-PcmdLineArgs=, -PjvmLineArgs=, -c, /home/naveed/data/work/projects/browngrid/bunnycrm/tech_upgrade/bunnycrm/source/server-java/settings.gradle]

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-08-05 23:53:31.926  INFO 3582 --- [           main] c.b.bunnycrm.SampleDataJpaApplication    : Starting SampleDataJpaApplication on naveed-Lenovo-Z70-80 with PID 3582 (/home/naveed/data/work/projects/browngrid/bunnycrm/tech_upgrade/bunnycrm/source/server-java/build/classes/java/main started by naveed in /home/naveed/data/work/projects/browngrid/bunnycrm/tech_upgrade/bunnycrm/source/server-java)
2018-08-05 23:53:31.933  INFO 3582 --- [           main] c.b.bunnycrm.SampleDataJpaApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-05 23:53:32.089  INFO 3582 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3b69e7d1: startup date [Sun Aug 05 23:53:32 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-05 23:53:37.717  INFO 3582 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$791aa5b1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-05 23:53:38.542  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9996 (http)
2018-08-05 23:53:38.613  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-05 23:53:38.614  INFO 3582 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-08-05 23:53:38.642  INFO 3582 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-08-05 23:53:38.925  INFO 3582 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-05 23:53:38.925  INFO 3582 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6839 ms
2018-08-05 23:53:39.091  INFO 3582 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-05 23:53:39.092  INFO 3582 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-08-05 23:53:39.511  INFO 3582 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-08-05 23:53:39.850  INFO 3582 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:39 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:40 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:40 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:40 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Sun Aug 05 23:53:40 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-08-05 23:53:40.228  INFO 3582 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-08-05 23:53:40.272  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-08-05 23:53:40.408  INFO 3582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.4.Final}
2018-08-05 23:53:40.412  INFO 3582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-08-05 23:53:40.579  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2018-08-05 23:53:41.029  INFO 3582 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2018-08-05 23:53:41.125  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2018-08-05 23:53:50.720  WARN 3582 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
2018-08-05 23:53:50.721  INFO 3582 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-08-05 23:53:50.730  INFO 3582 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-08-05 23:53:50.735  INFO 3582 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-05 23:53:50.781  INFO 3582 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-05 23:53:50.792 ERROR 3582 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.browngrid.bunnycrm.SampleDataJpaApplication.main(SampleDataJpaApplication.java:12) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:574) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :run
```

Here is the gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.browngrid'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '2.0.1'
}

mainClassName = 'com.browngrid.bunnycrm.SampleDataJpaApplication'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.browngrid.bunnycrm.SampleDataJpaApplication'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/caarmen/maven/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')

    compile "junit:junit:4.11"

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch') 
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'){
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.logging'
    } 
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    //hibernate
    //    compile 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    //    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.4.Final'

    //    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager
    //    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.4.Final'






    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.4.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.4.Final'

    //    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.1.0.Final'
    //    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.2.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging
    //    compile group: 'org.jboss.logging', name: 'jboss-logging', version: '3.3.2.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logmanager/jboss-logmanager
    testCompile group: 'org.jboss.logmanager', name: 'jboss-logmanager', version: '2.1.4.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-envers', version: '5.3.4.Final'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
    //    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'

    //log4j
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.5'

    //apache commons
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6'

    //commons
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile 'commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1'
    compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1'
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' 
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.4'

    //Others
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.16' 
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.16' 

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api
    compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-core', version: '1.18'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.18'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13'
        }
```

Pleae note that the following portions of code have no impact when commented or uncommented:

```
 testCompile group: 'org.jboss.logmanager', name: 'jboss-logmanager', version: '2.1.4.Final'
```

Also JBoss exclusion from Spring Data JPA have no impact:

```
 compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'){
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.logging'
}
```

Here is the dependency tree using minimal number of spring dependencies used in build.gradle

```
runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'runtimeOnly ' instead).
                    +--- junit:junit:4.12
                    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
                    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -> 2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.4.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
                    |    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
                    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.10.0
                    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.10.0
                    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
                    |    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19
                    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.4.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.13
                    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.0.4.RELEASE
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.4.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.7.9
                    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.17.Final
                    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final -> 3.3.2.Final
                    |    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final -> 1.0.2.Final
                    |    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.22.0-GA
                    |    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
                    |    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.3.Final
                    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0 -> 1.3.4
                    |    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
                    |    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
                    |    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.2.Final
                    |    +--- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2
                    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.9.RELEASE
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.9.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.8.RELEASE (*)
                    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
                    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.0.8.RELEASE
                    |         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.13
                    \--- mysql:mysql-connector-java -> 5.1.46
```

Comment: If you run your application with the JVM argument `-verbose:class` that will let you see where the `org.jboss.logging.Logger` class that does not have the required method is being loaded from.

Comment: Thanks @AndyWilkinson I know that its being called from HibernateJpaConfiguration. But I am not sure why HibernateJpaConfiguration is calling something which does not exist. I can basically get the source code and comment out the logger.debugf line. But this is a very common error on internet but I did not found any proper asnwer to that. It took me around 2 days in playing around the dependencies and still its not fixed.

Comment: It's calling something that doesn't exist is it does exist in the version of the class that it was compiled against. The version of the class that is being loaded to the version that was compiled against, so a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is thrown. Running with `-verbose:class` will allow you to see where the incompatible version of `org.jboss.logging.Logger` is being loaded from. With that information it should be possible to figure out what dependency needs to be excluded in your build to fix the problem.

Comment: How can I use following information to find the problem. My project is in Gradle so I have printed the dependency graph|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.17.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final -> 3.3.2.Final

|    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.1.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.3.Final
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.2.Final

Comment: Can you update your question with that output? The output from running with `-verbose:class` that’s related to JBoss logging would also be useful.

Comment: Yes I have updated the question. Everywhere hibernate needs org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.1.Final and founds 3.3.2.Final and it seems the latest 3.3.0 even does not have that method.

Comment: [3.3.2 has the method that's being called](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/3.3.2.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/Logger.java#L796-L800). You must have another version of `org.jboss.logging.Logger` on the class path somewhere. You can figure that out by running with `-verbose:class` and seeing where that class is loaded from.

Comment: You are right. As I am using Gradle, so I am not sure how to use -verbose:class with gradle. I tried to remove all other jars and then problem went away. But one thing which I am not sure is why one of these jars might have an old Logger class bean-validator.jar
dynamicreports-adhoc-5.0.0.jar
dynamicreports-core-5.0.0.jar
dynamicreports-googlecharts-5.0.0.jar 
lucene-analyzers-common-6.0.0.jar
lucene-core-6.0.0.jar
lucene-queryparser-6.0.0.jar
org.apache.batik.*.jar

Comment: And thanks a lot for your all comments. You can post an answer and I will accept it as a solution.